# Update id of a control in a page under contenttemplate from a custom user control?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sharepoint, user-controls

i have a control in my sharepoint page

```
    <asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<SharePointWebControls:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Literal runat="server" id="Literal1" text="" visible="false"></asp:Literal>



    i am trying to access this literal1 from a usercontrol and change the text value of this control or change the ID value of  this control.
```

i tried this to update id of a DIV control but it didnot work.  this is part of the user control.

```
      HtmlGenericControl control = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)this.Page.FindControl("literal");
        if (control != null)
        {
            control.Attributes.Clear();
            control.Attributes.Add(ID,divid);
            //control.Text = divid.ToString();
            //document.getElementById('var_div').setAttribute('id',val)

        }
```

any idea how it is going to work anyone

Answer (score 0):

Literal is render to nothing.
Try to use Label instead.